# android server for braodcasting to mutlitple users

Tags: http, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging, server

I want to set up a server for broadcasting same message to multiple users at the same time. I went through the GCM official documentation, it says that - "XMPP" does not support "multicasting" (sending same message to more than one user). HTTP could be used for that.

If that is the case, why there are a lot of articles on XMPP implementation and none on HTTP.

It makes me think that XMPP might be used as well.

Please suggest which one to use. If HTTP is the answer, share some links that explain the implementation.

Comment: [HKMCode](http://hmkcode.com/android-google-cloud-messaging-tutorial/) It uses HTTP protocol, basically only upstream messaging. XMPP allows downstream messaging which is useful to notify users. You could use XMPP and HTTP together.

Answer (score 1):

GCM XMPP interface does not support putting a list of recipient for a single push, but you can still send several pushes in parallel (on the multiple XMPP connections you may have).

For sending push notifications, what is typically more efficient depend on your usage pattern:

- If you send a lot of notifications to many users, XMPP may be better, as you can have several parallel streams.
- If you typically send the same notification to many users, then HTTP may be more efficient as a single notification can reach 1000 recipients at once.

As suggested, if your usage pattern is multiple, you can use both and select the most efficient approach dynamically.

However, it may not be worth the effort as you really need to send a lot of notifications to see a difference. Give you mention sending notifications to multiple users, my own personal suggestion would be to use the simpler HTTP approach and try the XMPP connector of GCM if you feel this becomes a bottleneck for some part of your usage.

Comment: I need this set up for a pure Group Chat, where a message sent by a user will be received by a lot of other users. Thus I guess, I will need something with which I can push the same notification to a lot of users.

Comment: Then, GCM HTTP based notification is fine :)